# PostgreSQL performance issue with "where" condition

Tags: postgresql, performance

When I run query the execution time is about 1 minute.

When I try to filter the data using "where":

```
select * from t1 where goal_id = '57'
```

the execution time is much longer (i can't wait to finish)
What problem with this query? What should i improve?

Comment: Do you have an index on `goal_id`? Is `goal_id` a number? If yes, then compare it to a number, `goal_id = 57`

Comment: Please show us an `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` of the 1 minute query, an just an EXPLAIN of the never-finishing query.